# How can i get image data from sql DataBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, system.io.file

I saved my file in the database, I want to get that file for sending mail If I wrote where the condition

```
 public EMS_PROFILE_UPLOAD_MASTER GetHrUploadeProfile(string EnqId)
 {
     var x = from n in db.EMS_PROFILE_UPLOAD_MASTER 
             where n.ENQUIRY_CODE== EnqId
             select n;

     foreach(var fileData in x)
     {
         var _FilData = fileData.FILEDATA;
     }

     return x.FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

I'm getting data but here I have multiple files in my database, how can I differentiate that file?

Comment: `how can i differentiate that file` I don't understand what that means.

Comment: @mjwills Here i have soomany files with same Id when i write above query its fetches all the files in single stream ..Then i dont have any controles over the files

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have multiple files with the same ID - means you cannot use the ID as the selector. Inside your code example, it seems that there may be other meta-data from that fileData object - what is inside that to further filter or control your selection for the correct file?